# array size defined with a variable

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to define an array whose size is defined by a variable, something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static class Items{
        int size;
        String[] elements = new String[size];
    }

    public static class Application {
        public doSomething() {
            Items i = new Items();
            i.size = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Looks weird to me, but I noticed it in a legacy code, hence I would like to know the semantics for this.

Comment: `"Is it possible"` - What happens when you test it?

Comment: TL;DR - **Yes**, you can create an array using the current value of a variable for the size. However, subsequent changes to the variable **do not** change the length of the array you've already created.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's a *field*, so it has default value `0`. Code compiles and runs, but makes no sense, since setting the `size` will not re-size the array.

Comment: Lot of heated comments on a simple question, all I was asking was the semantics of the above code, not to pass a judgement on the code (I have already mentioned that the code *was* weired)! From Andy's comments, it looks like the answer is that an array of size 0 will be created, irrespective of the value that is set to size. Did I understand right?

Comment: Andy, if I have understood your comment correctly, please post an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: And to answer another comment, yes the code is legal, it does not report a compiler error. But I am not yet sure what the allocation is, because I have not yet debugged this legacy code. Hence I had asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

An array has a static length(size) when created. That length is stored in the array as Array.length.

Make item something like this:

```
public static class Items {
    public Items(int size) {
        elements = new String[size];
    }
    public String[] elements;
}
```

Then you create items like Items items = new Items(10);

And retrieve the size by doing *myItem*.elements.length or make a getter if you want elements to be private.

**However** unless you intend to add methods, this wrapper is probably not necessary

Answer (score 0):

initialize size variable befor use

```
public static class Items{
    int size = 15;     // initialize size
    String[] elements = new String[size];
}
```